# Correct database technology for a realtime social game leaderboard

Tags: mongodb, scale, database

I'd like to start and apologize if my question doesn't follow the rules for SE.

We're designing a social game that should support millions of players, and I have a very specific question.

Let's say a Player looks like this:

```
{ ID: "423erRRWEfwm432we", Name: "Friend A", Score: 125, AvatarType: 3.... }
```

Now when someone logs into the game, we'd like to load all of his friends scores to show to him - now a person could have up to 2,000 friends.

I was wondering what would be the most efficient and scalable DB tech + method to load all of my friends' data (score, name, avatar, etc) - assuming this should be (fairly) realtime and players are going to login a lot.

EDIT:
I think I should have been a bit more specific, I am quite proficient when it comes to RDBMes and NoSQL DBs - my question was what would be the most efficient/scalable way of achieving this - we are currently using a sharded MongoDB environment on a production game and we're not happy to say the least from it's performance.

Answer (score 0):

In database terms, you have a table (ie "PLAYER"), with a self reference (ie a Player may have 0 or more "friends" who are also players). Since a Player may also be friends with 0 or more Players, it's what's referred to as a Many to Many reference. The common way of resolving this is with another table placed between the two tables (in your case, the two tables are the same table ;) ).  So create a table called "FRIENDS" or something, with 2 columns:  ID and FRIEND_ID.  Then create 1 row for each friend relationship. You just have to join / lookup that reference to get the list of Players who are friends to the logged in player.

The actual details/syntax of that solution vary slightly from 1 database to another.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply - I guess I should have been more specific - I've edited my reply to better explain our situation.

Comment: I don't see anything in your edit that changes my answer .. solution is still to create a relationship table to link Players with "Friends". I'm not familiar with MongoDB, however, so you'll have to figure out how to apply that in there.

Comment: Hey @Ditto, thanks again - I'll try to expand here - we are doing a social game with millions of players that can have thousands of friends, and these will be accessing the scores on a regular basis (we see around 650K RPM more or less at our peak) - using RDBMS would kill our performance and won't really improve anything in that matter.

Comment: _using_ _RDBMS_ _would_ _kill_ _our_ _performance_  Not sure I really believe that statement ... but whatever.  Have you tried it?  have you *proven* that it kills your performance? Or are you just making assumptions about RDBMS ??  Quick google search turns this up: http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/philg/2011/01/10/how-many-updates-per-second-can-a-standard-rdbms-process/    In their example, Oracle was handling a few thousand updates .. **per second** ... I'm thinking that most RDBMS can handle your (really slow) 650 / **minute**  very very easily ;) try it (in development of course)

Comment: that's **650,000 per minute**, right now we see around 20,000 updates per second

Comment: oh, missed the K .. lol sorry .. still .. most RDBMs should handle that if things are built properly ..